# Kinesis Glue S3 takes more than a minute to generate new data

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-glue, amazon-athena, amazon-kinesis

I'm trying to implement a real-time or near real-time pipeline that updates roughly every 5 seconds.

I created a producer that writes 1 record per second to a kinesis data stream and Hooked it up to a glue job running spark streaming. Once I ran the job I observed the updating of the data in s3 and Athena, and observed that it took 2-3 minutes to batch and save new data.

I upped the number of workers from 2 to 20, but this only sped it up to an update for every 1-2 minutes.

Is this a limitation of spark and how they say spark is near real-time and not actual real-time?

I'm going to attempt to implement something faster with lambda and dynamodb, but I'd really like to know if 5 second updates using Glue is a thing.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> By default, AWS Glue processes and writes out data in 100-second
> windows. This allows data to be processed efficiently and permits
> aggregations to be performed on data arriving later than expected. You
> can modify this window size to increase timeliness or aggregation
> accuracy.

You could try using [this function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context.html#aws-glue-api-crawler-pyspark-extensions-glue-context-forEachBatch) and changing the `windowSize`